# Font in Google android emulator?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I've been trying for the past week to find what is the font on google android emulator... :

[image]

But couldnt find any matches.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font is called "Clockopia" and you can download it here as a TTF:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/jb-dev/data/fonts

The font *only* includes glyphs for the digits `0` to `9`, `:`, and the letters `A`, `M`, and `P`.  If you preview the font in Windows it may be misleading, because all the other letters will be replaced with a substitute font.

Sample of font:

[image]

It seems that most Android devices replace this font with something else which is why you may have only seen it on the Android emulator.

According to the font file, it was designed by Jim Ford of Ascender Corporation, and it carries a Google copyright and trademark notice suggesting that Google commissioned the font.  According to the readme file at the above link, these font files are licensed under the Apache license 2.0 which means you're free to use them as you like, but if you modify and re-distribute them you must follow the license terms.

Answer (score 1):

I think that might be unique to emulator. I couldn't find any Android documentation of it. Closest match I found was Play on Google Fonts by Jonas Hecksher
[image]